# Django : How to extract full address previously saved as default in template

Tags: python, django

I have made a checkout process where users can add a new address and set it as default for next orders

The address contains Street_address, Street address2, Province, Country, Postal_Code and Phone.

I wanted to show the full default address before proceeding. I have reached to the point where I show the Street_address only but I tried to show the rest but failed.

How to extract the rest of the address?
This is the view:

```
class CheckoutView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            form = CheckoutForm()
            context = {
                'form': form,
                'couponform': CouponForm(),
                'order': order,
            }
            shipping_address_qs = Address.objects.filter(
                user=self.request.user,
                address_type='S',
                default='True'
            )
            if shipping_address_qs.exists():
                context.update(
                    {'default_shipping_address': shipping_address_qs[0]})
def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        try:
            order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
            if form.is_valid():

                use_default_shipping = form.cleaned_data.get(
                    'use_default_shipping')
                if use_default_shipping:
                    print("Using the defualt shipping address")
                    address_qs = Address.objects.filter(
                        user=self.request.user,
                        address_type='S',
                        default=True
                    )
                    if address_qs.exists():
                        shipping_address = address_qs[0]
                        order.shipping_address = shipping_address
                        order.save()
                    else:
                        messages.info(
                            self.request, "No default shipping address available")
                        return redirect('core:checkout')
                else:
                    print("User is entering a new shipping address")
                    shipping_address1 = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_address')
                    shipping_address2 = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_address2')
                    shipping_province = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_province')
                    shipping_country = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_country')
                    shipping_postal_code = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_postal_code')
                    shipping_phone_number = form.cleaned_data.get(
                        'shipping_phone_number')

                    if is_valid_form([shipping_address1, shipping_province, shipping_country, shipping_postal_code, shipping_phone_number]):
                        shipping_address = Address(
                            user=self.request.user,
                            street_address=shipping_address1,
                            apartment_address=shipping_address2,
                            province=shipping_province,
                            country=shipping_country,
                            postal_code=shipping_postal_code,
                            phone_number=shipping_phone_number,
                            address_type='S'
                        )
                        shipping_address.save()

                        order.shipping_address = shipping_address
                        order.save()

                        set_default_shipping = form.cleaned_data.get(
                            'set_default_shipping')
                        if set_default_shipping:
                            shipping_address.default = True
                            shipping_address.save()

                    else:
                        messages.info(
                            self.request, "Please fill in the required shipping address fields")

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.warning(self.request, "You do not have an active order")
            return redirect("core:order-summary")
```

this is the template

```
              {% if default_shipping_address %}
              <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="use_default_shipping" id="use_default_shipping">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="use_default_shipping">Use default shipping address: {{ default_shipping_address.street_address}}</label>
              </div>
              {% endif %}
```

This is the model:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    apartment_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    province = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = CountryField(multiple=False)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ADDRESS_CHOICES)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Addresses'
```

Comment: Are you facing any issues in accessing other fields ? in same way as street_address ?

Comment: `<label class="custom-control-label" for="use_default_shipping">Use default shipping address: {{ default_shipping_address.street_address}}</label>` are you taking about here. as here you have only `street_address`.

Comment: `<label class="custom-control-label" for="use_default_shipping">Use default shipping address: {{ default_shipping_address.street_address}}</label>` are you taking about here. as here you have only `street_address`.

Comment: @UmairMohammad yes I can not access Street_address2, Province, Country, Postal_Code and Phone.

Comment: @shivank98 yes I have tried adding `{{ default_shipping_address.street_address2}}`  and so on but it didnt work

Comment: There is no `Street_address2` in Address model so we can't access it. What error are you getting while fetching country, etc ?

Comment: @UmairMohammad yes you are right, post  it and I will accept it as an answer, it solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix : `Street address2` doesn't see to be there in your `Address`. So we can't access it.
Other fields should be accessible.

Another way: Add a `@property` to `Address` model to get the formatted address.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have the following str function in your Address class.

```
def __str__(self):
        return self. street_address + self.apartment_address # and so on if you want.
```

also, you were mentioning the only `street_address` so only that would be shown.
once you have updated your `__str__` function you can do the following also.

```
 <label class="custom-control-label" for="use_default_shipping">Use default shipping address: {{ default_shipping_address}}</label>
```